# jQuery - Looping over all elements and removing those with a specific attribute

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm new to jQuery and am still learning the syntax. I need help looping over all of the checkboxes in a specific form and remove those elements that I set with a "value" of x from the server. The syntax I have so far, which is not working is:

```
$('#FormA > :checkbox').each(function() {
     var i = $(this);
     if(i.attr('value') == "-99")
     {
          i.remove();   
     }
});
```

It looks after reading the API that under the hood the .each() method does a "java enhanced for loop" style iteration on all of the DOM elements that I pass into jQuery. Not sure though...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you perhaps create a jsFiddle to illustrate your problem? It's entirely possible that your selector isnt matching to all the elements you think it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most jQuery methods are applied to every element in the matched set. To do what you are trying to do, you just need to select the right set of elements and call `remove`. There's no need for the `each`. For example:

```
$("#FormA > :checkbox[value='-99']").remove();
```

This uses an ["attribute equals" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find checkbox input elements with a `value` of `-99`. It then removes all of the selected elements from the DOM.

The docs for [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) make this clear:

> Remove the **set of matched elements** from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks James! Great explanation...Matt

Answer (score 4):

Try using attribute selector,

```
$('#FormA > :checkbox[value=-99]').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this might work:

`$("#FormA :checkbox[value=-99]").remove()`

Answer (score 1):

Look Ma no jQuery! Little late to the party, but a pure JS way.

​

```
var form = document.getElementById("formA");

[].forEach.call(form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][value="-99"]'),function(el){form.removeChild(el);});​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yp6dW/)**

Also its MAGNITUDES faster.

**[JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/foreach-remove-vs-jqueryeach)**

Comment: I do like the answer, but it would be improved by highlighting the trade-offs, e.g. http://caniuse.com/queryselector & syntatic sugar vs. gaining MAGNITUDES on what scale of importance.

Comment: Also, I only got one magnitude difference: http://jsperf.com/foreach-remove-vs-jqueryeach/3

Answer (score 0):

Your selector will most likely work if you use $('#FormA :checkbox'), the way you have it right now, requires that the checkbox be an immediate descendant of the form.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
$('.YourClass:checked').each(function(){
i=$(this)
if(i.val()=='-99'){i.remove()}
})
```